# Django forms, html tags are showing up as text on front end

Tags: html, css, django

[image: This is what I'm getting on my front end]

```
<div class="form-group">
<span class="form-label">First Name</span>
<input class="form-control" type="{{ form.firstname }}" placeholder="Enter Employees First Name">
</div>
```

How do I fix this? All the placeholder values and the ">" are being shown as text. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you generating html in a template as something like `{{obj.html}}` or `{{view.html_property}}`? Django will do this as a security measure unless you mark it as safe. One way is `{{obj.html|safe}}` and another is to supply a safe string rather than an ordinary string. `format_html` does this for you.

Comment: I have this on top of my form.html.:

{% extends 'TB/navbar.html' %}

{% block content %}


 The rest of the code HTML is in a body tag

@nigel222 https://jsfiddle.net/u9y6nr1p/1/

I will look into some of the methods you have suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because using `{{form.firstname}}` renders a full input field.
If you looked at your source code you would find something similar to this:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="<input type="text" name="first_name" id="id_first_name">" placeholder="Enter Employees First Name">
```

Some browsers are smart enough to render the embedded `<input>` field correctly and that is why you are left with a form field and additional things around it.

To actually achieve what you want, you need to apply the placeholder as a widget in the `forms.py`. I don't know exactly how your form looks like, so I just show you a version of it using `forms.ModelForm`:

```py
class UpdatePersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        widgets = {
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Employees First Name'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdatePersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

I also added the class attribute `form-control` so that your input fields would have that class as well.
You can find out more about this in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)
I hope I could help you.
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `|safe` in `{{form.firstname | safe}}` or wherever the tags are printing on the frontend. If it doesn't work, then check all the frontend's closing tags.